# Upgraded to windows 10 but now I want to swap out my hdd for an SSD. How can I still get windows 10?

Tags: windows

Trying to do this in my laptop. Do I have to call microsoft? Laptop actually came with vista, but I had a free upgrade to 7 since it came out a couple months after I got the laptop.

Comment: Create an installation media, install Windows 10, Windows 10 will automatically activate.  You have to either have already upgraded to Windows 10 on the machine or install Version 1511 and use the Windows 7 key for what I describe to work.

Comment: your activation is allegedly tied to your motherboard. So you can change the HDD and install a fresh Windows 10 without problems as long as you don't replace your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [source](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-license-hardware-configuration) it should still work

> If you change Hard Disk or add a new hard disk, you will have to check
>   whether Windows still shows activated. Though the Microsoft Answer
>   Desk said that changing hard disks will not affect your activation, I
>   recommend checking it out.
>
> To check Windows 10 activation status, open Settings ? Update and
>   Security > Activation. You can see the status of Activation there. If
>   it says Windows 10 is not activated, click on Activate Now. That
>   should fix the issue. If not, you will have to contact the Microsoft
>   Answer Desk to activate on phone.